# malformed calls from sizes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to push images to the array .However with this code ,I am getting  the error 
'malformed calls from sizes'

Here is the code .

```
constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state={
             min_rating: 2 ,
             max_rating: 5 ,
         }
           this.star_with_rating=<Image source={require('../assets/images/star_filled.png')}/>;
           this. star_without_rating =<Image source={require('../assets/images/star_corner.png')}/>;
     }
render(){
          let arr=[];
           for( let index=1;index<=10;index++){
               arr.push(
                   <TouchableOpacity
                          activeOpacity={0.7}
                          key={index}
                          onPress={this.UpdateRating(index)}>
                          <Image
                             source={
                             index <= this.state.min_rating
                             ? {uri:this.star_with_rating} 
                              : {uri:this.star_without_rating}
                             }
                          />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

               )
           }
```

However when i remove the uri portion inside Image component ,i get the error this is a reserved word .

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are setting as the uri as Image component instead of a string. Which should be:

```
this.star_with_rating = '../assets/images/star_filled.png';
```

so also I would call it start_with_rating_uri

Check the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) for more details.